# Cisco Air-AP1252ag -- 15.2 can't get multiple SSIDs advertising properly

Tags: cisco, access-point

I'm having an issue with an AIR-AP1252ag that won't advertise multiple SSIDs in Beacons.  I'm trying to setup 3 SSIDs, 1 hidden (Controls), 1 Guest (works fine), 1 Internal Data-Wifi.

The problem is that the Internal Data WLAN is not sending the SSID in the beacons. To an end host/client, it just shows up like a hidden network.

I'm using c1250-k9w7-tar.152-2.JA.tar for the image.  And I'm starting to think from reading the config guide that I should just go back to 12.4. But I wanted to ask the question to see if anyone can help me set this up right first.  It *should* be fairly simple and I'm probably missing something silly.

Below is the config.  I've tried a mix of information-element ssidl advertisement with & without mbssid under the dot11 ssid. But I just can't figure out the right combination to get the ssid advertised properly.

```
!
dot11 syslog
!
dot11 ssid Controls
   vlan 32
   authentication open
   authentication key-management wpa version 2
   mbssid dtim-period 50
   wpa-psk ascii 7 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
!
dot11 ssid Guest
   vlan 31
   authentication open
   mbssid guest-mode dtim-period 75
   information-element ssidl advertisement
!
dot11 ssid Data-Wifi
   vlan 30
   authentication open
   authentication key-management wpa version 2
   mbssid dtim-period 75
   wpa-psk ascii 7 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   information-element ssidl advertisement
!
crypto pki token default removal timeout 0
!
!
username admin privilege 15 secret xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
!
!
bridge irb
!
!
interface Dot11Radio0
 no ip address
 no ip route-cache
 !
 encryption vlan 30 mode ciphers aes-ccm tkip
 !
 encryption vlan 32 mode ciphers aes-ccm tkip
 !
 ssid Controls
 !
 ssid Guest
 !
 ssid Data-Wifi
 !
 antenna gain 0
 mbssid
 station-role root access-point
 bridge-group 1
 bridge-group 1 subscriber-loop-control
 bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning
 no bridge-group 1 unicast-flooding
!
interface Dot11Radio0.30
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 no ip route-cache
!
interface Dot11Radio0.31
 encapsulation dot1Q 31
 no ip route-cache
!
interface Dot11Radio0.32
 encapsulation dot1Q 32
 no ip route-cache
!
interface Dot11Radio1
 no ip address
 no ip route-cache
 shutdown
 antenna gain 0
 dfs band 3 block
 channel dfs
 station-role root
 bridge-group 1
 bridge-group 1 subscriber-loop-control
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
 bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning
 no bridge-group 1 unicast-flooding
!
interface GigabitEthernet0
 no ip address
 no ip route-cache
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 bridge-group 1
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning
!
interface GigabitEthernet0.30
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 no ip route-cache
!
interface GigabitEthernet0.31
 encapsulation dot1Q 31
 no ip route-cache
!
interface GigabitEthernet0.32
 encapsulation dot1Q 32
 no ip route-cache
!
interface BVI1
 ip address 172.16.99.15 255.255.255.0
 no ip route-cache
!
bridge 1 route ip
bridge 1 protocol ieee
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Data-Wifi` doesn't have guest-mode enabled (`mbssid guest-mode`) so it will not beacon.

See Also: [guest-mode](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/12-4_10b_JA/command/reference/cr2410b/cr12410b-chap2.html#wp3659596) and [mbssid guest-mode](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/12-4_10b_JA/command/reference/cr2410b/cr12410b-chap2.html#wp2702003)